# Como INFORMAR o nome de um objeto contido em Arrays?

Tags: javascript

estou praticando um pouco com Arrays essa semana e ao criar o script abaixo eu pensei 'será que posso retornar o NOME do objeto contido no array ao invés de apenar retornar seu índice numérico?'.
O seguinte script faz uma análise rápida nos objetos da minha Array, e em seguida retorna no console se foi ou não encontrado, como posso escrever o nome do objeto que buscamos no resultado de sucesso?

```js
let lista_frutas = ['Banana', 'Uva', 'Morango']
 let auxiliar = lista_frutas.indexOf('Morango')


if (auxiliar === -1){
  console.log('Não encontramos essa fruta')
} else {
  console.log('Sua fruta está bem aqui no índice No. ' + lista_frutas.indexOf('Morango'))
// queria exibir bem aqui, no console, algo como 'Sua fruta está bem aqui, encontramos seu MORANGO'
}
```

Comment: `indexOf` retorna o índice do elemento, então basta fazer `lista_frutas[auxiliar]`. Mas vc já sabe que está buscando por "Morango", afinal vc faz `lista_frutas.indexOf('Morango')`, então o resultado só pode ser "Morango", bastava imprimir a palavra diretamente...

Comment: Se bem que no seu caso, vc só quer ver se o array contém a string "Morango", então bastava fazer `if (lista_frutas.includes("Morango")) { encontrado } else { não encontrado }`

Answer (score -2):

Existe o método `find()`, que retorna o valor do primeiro elemento do array que satisfaça a condição, exemplo:

```
let lista_frutas = ['Banana', 'Uva', 'Morango'];
let auxiliar = 'Morango';
if (!lista_frutas.find((a) => a === auxiliar)) {
console.log('Não encontramos essa fruta')
} else {
console.log('A sua fruta é', auxiliar)
}
```

O que esse código está fazendo é: No primeiro `if` a denotação **!** significa que ele espera que dê **false** para entrar neste primeiro bloco, ou seja, caso não encontre a fruta Morango, retorno aquele bloco, se não, ele exibe a fruta.

Essa é uma das maneiras que pode se fazer, sugiro você ler neste [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) sobre esse método `find()` que é bem interessante.

Comment: Nesse trecho 'if (!lista_frutas.find((a) => a === auxiliar))' vejo muitas pessoas usando coisas semelhantes, mas ainda não aprendi como exatamente deveria 'ler' esse tipo de bloco. Aquele (a) ali é justamente a letra inicial da minha variável 'auxiliar'? Se sim, deve ser sempre a primeira letra da variável selecionada ou posso definir um 'i' como já vi fazerem? Mas em suma, muito obrigado <3

Comment: O if ele espero que o que está entre os parênteses seja verdadeiro, ou seja, if (condição verdadeira) {...executa o código aqui}, então quando coloca a denotação !, ele espera que a condição dentro dos parênteses seja falsa.

O a é um parâmetro genérico, poderia ser qualquer coisa ali dentro. Indico novamente ler sobre o método find( ) e após, ler também sobre callbacks e funções anônimas e esse trecho de código acredita que começará a ficar mais claro. Bons Estudos!

Comment: @Kazbonfim `(a) => a === auxiliar` é uma função que recebe um parâmetro (que no caso foi chamado de `a`), e retorna se ele é igual ao valor de `auxiliar` (que é a string que vc está buscando). O que `find` faz é chamar essa função para cada elemento do array (ou seja, vai chamar várias vezes, e a cada vez o `a` será um dos elementos), e se retornar `true`, ele retorna o elemento.